# Image slideshow with a book/page flip effect

Tags: images, flash, embed

Do you know of an application that can make embeddable flash image galleries that have a page flip effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find on:

1. http://page-flip.com/demos.htm
2. http://www.actionscript.org/showMovie.php?id=459
3. http://www.flash-filter.net/page-flip-effect.phtml

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Free try below programs:

1. http://www.kvisoft.com/flipbook-maker-pro/ (desktop program)
2. http://www.pageflip-flap.com/ (online free service)

They can create image gallery with page flippable effect.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the products, please disclose that in your answer.